# $V_{\epsilon}(x^*)$ notation

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

What does the following notation $V_{\epsilon}(x^*)$ in the context

> and there are infinitely many terms of $a_n$ in $V_{\epsilon}(x^*)$

on this [link](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/limit-superior-and-limit-inferior).

Comment: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-real-line-and-the-epsilon-neighbourhood-of-a-real-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context it looks like the interval
$$
V_{\epsilon}(x)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\ .
$$